# How to Directly Import Better Example Images for MWEs

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, fbox, crop-image

For the purpose of asking questions on this site related to images, I know that I can directly call in a basic non-descriptive image in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}\\
%\fbox{\includegraphics[trim=1 150 0 0,scale=0.1]{tiger}}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

However, in some instances, an actual picture such as

[image]

would be more desirable.

I know that the above framed tiger can be produced with the command

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[trim=1 150 0 0,scale=0.1]{tiger}}
```

But it seems that this `tiger` image cannot be called in by the package `graphicx`.

Is the tiger image, as well as perhaps others like it, available for use directly by calling in some package? I suppose I can save this image which so often appears on this site to my computer and call it in that way, but then, someone who is going to answer the question I post will not be able to run my MWE without error.

QUESTION: What is the simplest way to incorporate the Latex tiger (and similar-type images) into a MWE for the purpose of asking a question on this site?

Thank you.

Comment: the tiger is not a "latex tiger", it has been one of the standard ghostscript test postscript files since forever. It is not in the standard texlive input tree so not directly available to examples

Comment: @David Carlisle So, may I surmise then, that there are no (real picture) `example-image`(s) that I can access directly, other than perhaps, images from `tikzlings` as suggested by Marijn's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tiger is a ghostscript test eps file not from the latex distribution and isn't in the default input tree.

There are a few images that are and make a change from `example-image`, for example `\includegraphics{pink_marble}` or  `\includegraphics{mill}`.
The last one is from context but latex will find it.

A full list of png files in texlive input tree is

```
 for i in $(grep '\.png' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R) | sed -e 's/.*://' | sort | uniq ); do kpsewhich $i; done
```

which shows up the following, obviously you could do similar for jpg or eps.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_FOM_background.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_FOM_frametitlebackground.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_FOM_ifes_backgound.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_FOM_ifes_frametitlebackgound.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_FOM_ifes_logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_SC_logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_eufom_backgound.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_eufom_frametitlebackgound.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_eufom_linie.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/NPBT_eufom_logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/uowthesis/UoWlogo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/alertmessage/img/alertmessage-error.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/alertmessage/img/alertmessage-info.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/alertmessage/img/alertmessage-success.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/alertmessage/img/alertmessage-warning.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/blueshade.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides/cc-by-sa.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides/cc_somerights.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context-version.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/crinklepaper.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides/dangerous-bend.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iodhbwm/dhbw-logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/ep-ball-01.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/ep-ball-02.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/ep-ball-03.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/ep-ball-04.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elpres/ep-ball-05.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-grid-100x100bp.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-grid-100x100pt.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-10x16.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-16x10.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-16x9.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-1x1.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-4x3.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-9x16.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-c.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_acid-8.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_acid.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_aqpol.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_bottle-2-black.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_bottle-2-white.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_bottle.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_exclam.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-1.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-2.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-3.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-4.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-5.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos-6.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_explos.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-2-black.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-2-white.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-3-black.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-3-white.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-4-1.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-4-2.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-4-3-black.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-4-3-white.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-5-2-black.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-5-2-white.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-O-5-1.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame-O.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_flame.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_health.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_skull-2.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_skull-6.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ghsystem/pictures/ghsystem_skull.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/goldshade.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/notes/hand.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ijsra/ijsra_logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/notes/info.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides/jacobs-logo.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamertheme-npbt/images/lNPBT_SC_linie.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp_baseline_marker.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/sample/common/mill.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/optex/demo/op-ring.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/optex/demo/op-slides-bg.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/pink_marble.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stex/mikoslides/shading-l2r.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sillypage/sillywalk-map.png
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/notes/warn.png
```

and finally one complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{mill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer.

Answer (score 3):

What is contained within an image is not something that should influence the way you handle the solution. You can definitely phrase the question and use an example image from [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe). That's the beauty of what `mwe` provides (from its [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/mwe):

> Once installed in the correct directory in the TEXMF tree they will be available to all documents. This way a user can compile any MWE given to him by another person which uses these image files without requiring code replacements or sharing images.

If you think the images are bland and need more colour, then use a `page` from `example-image-a4-numbered` or `example-image-letter-numbered`:

```
\includegraphics[page=10]{example-image-letter-numbered]
```

[image]

There's also `example-grid-100x100pt` and `example-grid-100x100bp`:

[image]

If you want to include a "sample document" (looking for more text), there's `example-image-letter` and `example-image-letter-landscape` (and other sizes, like `a3`, `a4` and `a5`).

In my opinion, the `mwe` package elements are probably one of the most-used but least-mentioned elements (on this site), since you don't have to `\usepackage{mwe}` in order to use the images.

For reference, the `tiger` image is available within some package location. See, for example, [`tiger.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/yathesis/exemples/specimen/tiger.pdf) from [`yathesis`](//ctan.org/pkg/yathesis) and [`tiger.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-base/doc/latex/tiger.pdf) from [`tkz-base`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-base). So these exist within the TeX Directory Structure (TDS), but you'll have to change `\graphicspath`, or reference them directly (`\includegraphics[..]{path/to/image/tiger}`).

In short, using a "more desirable" image doesn't make the question better. You should be able to ask the question in such a way that it doesn't require any specific image (that is not contained within/distributed with `mwe`).

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this very informative answer. I was not aware of many of the things you point out. My reason for asking the question is because I anticipate asking a question(s) on transparent images in the future and I  thought something along the lines of a real image instead of a "bland" image box would make it easier for me to demonstrate what I would be looking for. But I understand your comment about specific images. Thanks again for this most helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a less boring image you can use the `tikzlings` package, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\sloth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no tiger in `tikzlings` though.

For the tiger can include the original source of the `.eps` file with `filecontents`. Here the outline only, to keep the code shorter:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tiger.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2
%%BoundingBox: 1 150 611 792
/InitDictCount countdictstack def
gsave
save
mark
newpath
/showpage {} def
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2
%%Creator: Adobe Illustrator(TM) 1.2d4
%%For: OpenWindows Version 2
%%Title: tiger.eps
%%CreationDate: 4/12/90 3:20 AM
%%DocumentProcSets: Adobe_Illustrator_1.2d1 0 0
%%DocumentSuppliedProcSets: Adobe_Illustrator_1.2d1 0 0
%%BoundingBox: 22 171 567 738
%%EndComments

%%BeginProcSet:Adobe_Illustrator_1.2d1 0 0

/Adobe_Illustrator_1.2d1 dup 100 dict def load begin
% definition operators
/bdef {bind def} bind def
/ldef {load def} bdef
/xdef {exch def} bdef
% graphic state operators
/_K { 3 index add neg dup 0 lt {pop 0} if 3 1 roll } bdef
/_k /setcmybcolor where {
    /setcmybcolor get
} {
    { 1 sub 4 1 roll _K _K _K setrgbcolor pop } bind
} ifelse def
/g {/_b xdef /p {_b setgray} def} bdef
/G {/_B xdef /P {_B setgray} def} bdef
/k {/_b xdef /_y xdef /_m xdef /_c xdef /p {_c _m _y _b _k} def} bdef
/K {/_B xdef /_Y xdef /_M xdef /_C xdef /P {_C _M _Y _B _k} def} bdef
/d /setdash ldef
/_i currentflat def
/i {dup 0 eq {pop _i} if setflat} bdef
/j /setlinejoin ldef
/J /setlinecap ldef
/M /setmiterlimit ldef
/w /setlinewidth ldef
% path construction operators
/_R {.25 sub round .25 add} bdef
/_r {transform _R exch _R exch itransform} bdef
/c {_r curveto} bdef
/C /c ldef
/v {currentpoint 6 2 roll _r curveto} bdef
/V /v ldef
/y {_r 2 copy curveto} bdef
/Y /y ldef
/l {_r lineto} bdef
/L /l ldef
/m {_r moveto} bdef
% path painting operators
/n /newpath ldef
/N /n ldef
/F {p fill} bdef
/f {closepath F} bdef
/S {P stroke} bdef
/s {closepath S} bdef
/B {gsave F grestore S} bdef
/b {closepath B} bdef
end
%%EndProcSet
%%EndProlog

%%Page: 1 1

Adobe_Illustrator_1.2d1 begin

.8 setgray
%clippath fill
-110 -300 translate
1.1 dup scale

0 g
0 G
0 i
0 J
0 j
0.172 w
10 M
[]0 d
0 0 0 0 k

177.696 715.715 m
177.797 713.821 176.973 713.84 v
176.149 713.859 159.695 761.934 139.167 759.691 C
156.95 767.044 177.696 715.715 V
b
181.226 718.738 m
180.677 716.922 179.908 717.221 v
179.14 717.519 180.023 768.325 159.957 773.199 C
179.18 774.063 181.226 718.738 V
b
208.716 676.41 m
210.352 675.45 209.882 674.773 v
209.411 674.096 160.237 686.898 150.782 668.541 C
154.461 687.428 208.716 676.41 V
b
205.907 666.199 m
207.763 665.803 207.529 665.012 v
207.296 664.221 156.593 660.879 153.403 640.478 C
150.945 659.563 205.907 666.199 V
b
201.696 671.724 m
203.474 671.061 203.128 670.313 v
202.782 669.565 152.134 673.654 146.002 653.936 C
146.354 673.175 201.696 671.724 V
b
190.991 689.928 m
192.299 688.554 191.66 688.033 v
191.021 687.512 147.278 713.366 133.131 698.324 C
141.872 715.467 190.991 689.928 V
b
183.446 685.737 m
184.902 684.52 184.326 683.929 v
183.75 683.339 137.362 704.078 125.008 687.531 C
131.753 705.553 183.446 685.737 V
b
180.846 681.665 m
182.454 680.657 181.964 679.994 v
181.474 679.331 132.692 693.554 122.709 675.478 C
126.934 694.251 180.846 681.665 V
b
191.58 681.051 m
192.702 679.52 192.001 679.085 v
191.3 678.65 151.231 709.898 135.273 696.793 C
146.138 712.674 191.58 681.051 V
b
171.8 710 m
172.4 708.2 171.6 708 v
170.8 707.8 142.2 749.8 122.999 742.2 C
138.2 754 171.8 710 V
b
172.495 703.021 m
173.47 701.392 172.731 701.025 v
171.993 700.657 135.008 735.501 117.899 723.939 C
130.196 738.739 172.495 703.021 V
b
172.38 698.651 m
173.502 697.12 172.801 696.685 v
172.1 696.251 132.031 727.498 116.073 714.393 C
126.938 730.274 172.38 698.651 V
b
0 J 1 w
170.17 696.935 m
170.673 690.887 171.661 684.318 173.4 681.199 C
169.8 668.799 178.6 655.599 V
178.2 648.399 179.8 645.199 V
183.8 636.799 188.6 635.999 v
192.484 635.352 201.207 632.283 211.068 630.879 c
228.2 616.799 225 603.999 V
224.6 587.599 221 585.999 V
232.6 597.199 223 580.399 V
218.6 561.599 l
244.2 583.199 228.6 564.799 V
218.6 538.799 l
238.2 557.199 231 548.799 V
227.8 539.999 l
271 567.199 240.2 537.599 V
248.2 541.199 252.6 538.399 V
259.4 539.599 258.6 537.999 V
237.8 527.599 234.2 509.199 V
242.6 519.199 239.4 508.399 V
239.8 496.799 l
243.8 518.399 243.4 480.799 V
262.6 498.799 251 477.999 V
251 461.199 l
266.2 477.599 259.8 464.799 V
269.8 473.599 265.8 458.399 V
265 447.999 269.4 459.199 V
285.4 489.799 279.4 463.599 V
278.6 444.399 283.4 459.199 V
283.8 448.799 293 441.599 V
291.8 492.399 304.6 456.399 V
308.6 439.999 l
311.4 449.199 311 454.399 V
325.8 470.799 319 446.399 V
334.2 469.199 331 455.999 V
323.4 439.999 325 435.199 V
341.8 469.999 343 471.599 V
341 429.198 351.8 465.199 V
357.4 453.199 354.6 448.799 V
362.6 456.799 361.8 459.999 V
366.4 468.199 369.2 454.599 V
371 445.199 372.6 448.399 V
376.6 424.398 377.8 447.199 V
379.4 460.799 372.2 472.399 V
373 475.599 370.2 479.599 v
383.8 457.999 376.6 486.799 V
387.801 478.799 389.001 478.799 V
375.4 501.999 384.2 497.199 V
379 507.599 397.001 495.599 V
381 511.599 398.601 501.999 V
406.601 495.599 399.001 505.599 V
384.6 521.599 406.601 503.599 V
418.201 487.199 419.001 484.399 V
409.001 513.599 404.601 516.399 V
413.001 552.799 454.201 537.199 V
461.001 519.999 465.401 538.399 V
478.201 544.799 489.401 517.199 V
493.401 530.799 492.601 533.599 V
499.401 532.399 498.601 533.599 V
511.801 529.199 513.001 529.999 V
519.801 523.199 520.201 526.799 V
529.401 523.999 527.401 527.599 V
536.201 511.999 536.601 508.399 V
539.001 522.399 l
541.001 519.599 l
542.601 527.199 541.801 528.399 v
541.001 529.599 561.801 521.599 566.601 500.799 C
568.601 492.399 l
574.601 507.199 573.001 511.199 V
578.201 510.399 578.601 505.999 V
582.601 529.199 577.801 535.199 V
582.201 535.999 583.401 532.399 V
583.401 539.599 l
590.601 538.799 590.601 541.199 V
595.001 545.199 597.001 540.399 V
584.601 575.599 603.001 556.399 V
610.201 545.599 606.601 564.399 v
603.001 583.199 599.001 584.799 603.801 585.199 C
604.601 588.799 602.601 590.399 v
600.601 591.999 603.801 590.399 y
608.601 586.399 603.401 608.399 V
609.801 606.799 597.801 635.999 V
600.601 638.399 596.601 646.799 V
604.601 642.399 607.401 643.999 V
607.001 645.599 603.801 649.599 V
582.201 704.4 602.601 682.399 V
614.451 668.849 608.051 691.649 V
598.94 715.659 599.717 719.955 V
170.17 696.935 l
b
0.2 0.55 0.85 0 k
599.717 719.755 m
600.345 719.574 602.551 718.45 603.801 716.8 C
610.601 706 605.401 724.4 V
596.201 753.2 605.001 742 V
611.001 734.8 607.801 748.4 v
603.936 764.827 601.401 771.2 y
613.001 766.4 586.201 806 V
595.001 802.4 l
575.401 842 553.801 847.2 V
545.801 853.2 l
584.201 891.2 571.401 928 V
564.601 933.2 555.001 924 V
548.601 919.2 542.601 920.8 V
511.801 919.6 509.801 919.6 v
507.801 919.6 473.001 956.8 407.401 939.2 C
402.201 937.2 397.801 938.4 V
379.4 954.4 330.6 931.6 v
320.6 929.6 319 929.6 v
317.4 929.6 314.6 929.6 306.6 923.2 c
298.6 916.8 298.2 916 296.2 914.4 C
279.8 903.2 275 902.4 V
263.4 896 259 886 V
255.4 884.8 l
253.8 877.6 253.4 876.4 V
248.6 872.8 247.8 867.2 V
239 861.2 239.4 856.8 V
237.8 851.6 237 846.8 V
229.8 842 230.6 839.2 V
223 825.2 224.2 818.4 V
217.8 818.8 215 816.4 V
214.2 811.6 212.6 811.2 V
209.8 810 212.2 806 V
210.6 803.2 210.2 801.6 V
211 798.8 206.6 793.2 V
200.2 774.4 202.2 769.2 V
202.6 764.4 199.8 762.8 V
196.2 763.2 204.6 751.2 V
205.4 750 202.2 747.6 V
185 744 182.6 727.6 V
169 712.8 169 707.6 v
169 705.295 169.271 702.148 169.97 697.535 C
169.4 689.199 197 688.399 v
224.6 687.599 599.717 719.755 Y
b
0 g
1 w
210.75 631 m
232.75 626.25 l
S
261 469 m
260.5 472.5 251.5 462 v
S
266.5 464 m
268.5 470.5 262 466 v
S
320.5 455.5 m
322 466.5 310.5 453.5 v
S

showpage

% Modification Denis GIROU (CNRS/IDRIS - France) <Denis.Girou@idris.fr> - 18 Dec. 1997
%% %%Trailer
countdictstack InitDictCount sub { end } repeat
cleartomark
restore
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{tiger}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Maybe for an MWE not ideal though :)

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. I could not produce your last image when I ran the code with pdflatex; however, it works fine with xelatex.

Comment: @mlchristians strange, I ran it with pdflatex. Maybe there is a problem with `epstopdf` on your system, which is called automatically by `graphicx` in order to use eps images with pdflatex. However, it was not a fully serious suggestion, any interesting image would be far to much code for an MWE :) it would be nice if the tiger could be included in the [MWE](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe) package from our former moderator Martin Scharrer for example, you could open a ticket on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-mwe/tickets/).

Comment: Thank you (and for pointing out SourceForge.)